# Show the a Level Label on a Org Chart Layout TreeView

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF TreeView that i have applied a Organizational Chart template. What I now need to do is find a way to add a Label that shows what Level Items are at. Example:

```
  ROOT LEVEL             Parent
                           |
                           |-----------| 
 CHILD LEVEL               CHILD 1     CHILD 2
                            |            |----------------|
GRANDCHILD LEVEL           GRANDCHILD1   GRANDCHILD2     GRANDCHILD3
```

I would think there is a template to edit to do this. However I can not find one. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Kevin's Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot). There's a control there: `OrgTree`, with a very good User Experience that does what you want. Most logic is at the Model level, so it's easy to tweak.

You can also find the very use

Comment: Hi @david-rodrigues, thanks for the response however BOT does not show if an item is selected and also does not easily allow me to do what i need and i have done most of what is in BOT for the OrgTree. Thanks